# Implement a function that rotates 90 degrees in a two-dimensional array that represents a color image

Tags: arrays, c, optimization, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I am trying to reduce the runtime of a particular function
This is the naive implementation:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short red;
    unsigned short green;
    unsigned short blue;
} pixel;

#define RIDX(i,j,n)  ((i)*(n)+(j))

void naive_rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I improve my runtime ?

Comment: Replace your uses of RIDX with what they expand into, and move as much work (esp. multiplications) out of the loops as possible.  (Hint: you can get this down to a single multiplication.)  Whether all that effort will speed things up much is a very open question.

Comment: There isn't a lot to improve.  If you're going to be able to do anything, I think it'll be modifying the way you access the arrays, simplifying the expressions currently encapsulated in `RIDX` so that you don't have to do two multiplications per assignment.  But it might well be that the optimizer already does that for you — you'd have to look at the generated assembly code to see what goes on (before and after any modifications).

Comment: Matrix rotations, like transposes, are notorious for performance problems. In-cache cases may be improved by SIMD features, depending on the processor model. Out-of-cache cases may be improved by blocking and other cache-sensitive techniques. You have not given enough information for further advice, like the image size, target processor, current performance, or desired performance.

Comment: Also, in the context of doing many image operations, it is sometimes desirable to remember and coalesce operations, performing them only when necessary, not individually, or to write routines that operate as desired on the unrotated image.

Comment: @PeterCordes: *micro-optimization* that makes the code 5x faster can be useful :)

Comment: @chqrlie: Yeah, that's why we have a tag for it. :)  I considered replacing [compiler-optimization] with [cpu-cache] or something, too, but image processing basically always has to be cache-aware for non-tiny images, so that's not going to help people find it.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/GYGxsb8zv) produced by **gcc** and **clang**, there is not much to improve besides choosing the appropriate optimisation options.

Here are a few ideas:

- You could try and help the compiler avoid extra multiplications, but these two already optimize that:

```
void naive_rotate1(int dim, const pixel *src, pixel *dst) {
    pixel *dst0 = dst + (dim - 1) * dim;

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        pixel *dst1 = dst0 + i;
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            *dst1 = *src++;
            dst1 -= dim;
        }
    }
}
```

- You could use `size_t` instead of `int` for the index types:

```
void naive_rotate2(size_t dim, const pixel *src, pixel *dst) {
    pixel *dst0 = dst + (dim - 1) * dim;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        pixel *dst1 = dst0 + i;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            *dst1 = *src++;
            dst1 -= dim;
        }
    }
}
```

- You could change your image representation and use 4 components instead of 3 to improve aligned accesses:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short red;
    unsigned short green;
    unsigned short blue;
    unsigned short alpha;
} pixel4;

void naive_rotate4(size_t dim, const pixel4 *src, pixel4 *dst) {
    pixel4 *dst0 = dst + (dim - 1) * dim;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        pixel4 *dst1 = dst0 + i;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            *dst1 = *src++;
            dst1 -= dim;
        }
    }
}
```

- You may improve cache locality by moving and rotating 8x8 subtiles instead of whole rows at a time.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short red;
    unsigned short green;
    unsigned short blue;
} pixel;

#define RIDX(i,j,n)  ((i)*(n)+(j))

void naive_rotate3(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int dim8 = dim - dim % 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < dim8; i += 8) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim8; j += 8) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 8; jj++) {
                    dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j - jj, i + ii, dim)] = src[RIDX(i + ii, j + jj, dim)];
                }
            }
         }
    }
    for (int i = dim8; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim8; i++) {
        for (int j = dim8; j < dim; j++) {
            dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
        }
    }
}
```

- Combining both tiles and 4 components:

```
void naive_rotate5(int dim, pixel4 *src, pixel4 *dst) {
    int dim8 = dim - dim % 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < dim8; i += 8) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim8; j += 8) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < 8; jj++) {
                    dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j - jj, i + ii, dim)] = src[RIDX(i + ii, j + jj, dim)];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = dim8; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim8; i++) {
        for (int j = dim8; j < dim; j++) {
            dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = src[RIDX(i, j, dim)];
        }
    }
}
```

- Let the compiler optimize for some specific sizes:

```
void naive_rotate6(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) {
    switch (dim) {
    case 16: naive_rotate(16, src, dst); break;
    case 64: naive_rotate(64, src, dst); break;
    default: naive_rotate(dim, src, dst); break;
}
```

You should benchmark these alternatives to measure actual performance, which may vary from one compiler/system to another.

On my system, I get these timings for 2048x2048 images:

```
naive_rotate(2048): 54.129ms
naive_rotate1(2048): 53.904ms
naive_rotate2(2048): 57.569ms
naive_rotate3(2048): 15.788ms
naive_rotate4(2048): 57.403ms
naive_rotate5(2048): 11.811ms
naive_rotate6(2048): 54.211ms
```

moving 8x8 subtiles achieves a remarkable **4x** to **5x** improvement on large images. 4x4 or 16x16 still outperform `naive_rotate`, but only by a factor of 2 on my old macBook.

For small specific sizes such as 16x16 and 64x64, `naive_rotate6` is faster by 20 to 50% on my benchmarks.

Comment: This implementation perform well on 1024x1024 but perform poor on 64x64 image.
3 times faster for large image but only 1.1-1.2 faster on 64x64 image.

Comment: @Code_m: that's true, small images tend to fit in the cache during the whole rotation process. As long as the more complex code does not degrade performance, you still have a win, otherwise you could test the size and select the appropriate algorithm.

Comment: Which model will fit best for small picture?I have checked all of them and they give the same time aprox....

Comment: @Code_m: for small pictures, the compiler might generate better code for constant sizes, such as 16x16 or 64x64. You might get better timings from testing for specific sizes and calling dedicated functions using constant dimensions (with the same basic code).

Comment: Can you provide an example.                                                                                        if(dim == 64){  .....} something like this?

Comment: @Code_m: I updated the answer with a simplistic `naive_rotate6` using a `switch` statement to optimize 16x16 and 64x64 cases. **clang** inlines the calls `naive_rotate(16, src, dst)` and `naive_rotate(64, src, dst)` and generates size specific code for these cases while still using the same code for others. This trick may or may not work for your environment. Make sure you pass `-O3` and possibly more architecture specific optimisation options.

Comment: @Code_m: this trick is very useful to optimize multiplications and divisions when common cases involve known constants such as `8`, `10` and `16`.

Comment: What do you  mean by" Make sure you pass -O3 and possibly more architecture specific optimisation options". I tried to shift right sometimes when I am sure that the multiplicationis 2 power. I am having hard time understand what you mean.

Comment: This discussion is vain unless you invoke your compiler with appropriate optimisation settings, such as `-O3` for **gcc** and **clang**.  Other architecture specific options may help produce more efficient code. Study the compiler documentation.

Comment: How can I do it? A differnce should be if I complie via terminal or via IDE?

Comment: @Code_m: if you compile at the command line or using a Makefile, the compiler flags are passed explicitly, possibly via the `$CFLAGS` environment variable. If you use an IDE with an integrated compiler, there should be an interface to set them up. Study the documentation or get help from fellow users of this environment.

Answer (score 1):

May be by removing some computations when accessing the `src` image? This way:

```
pixel *p = src;
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
        dst[RIDX(dim - 1 - j, i, dim)] = *p++;
```

Removing on `dst` is little more tricky (modulos and additions), not sure it will worth the effort (except if `dim` is a power of 2?).

Comment: @chqrlie Sure! What a stupid mistake! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could eliminate the multiplications (apart from the "hidden" multiplications by `sizeof(pixel)` in the pointer arithmetic) by using increment/decrement:

```
void naive_rotate(int dim, pixel *src, pixel *dst) 
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        pixel *savedst = dst;
        src += dim;
        for (j = 0; j < dim - 1; j++) {
            src--;
            *dst = *src;
            dst += dim;
        }
        src--;
        *dst = *src;
        src += dim;
        dst = savedst + 1;
    }
}
```

The last pixel of each row of the source image is handled as a special case to avoid pointer calculations going beyond the bounds of the image (although it they are allowed to reach the position just after the last pixel of the image). An alternative would be to handle the entire last row as a special case, which might be slightly faster but would use more code.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not equivalent to the OP's code.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, you are correct, it's more of a diagonal reflection. I'll hide it while fixing it!

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Comment: Seems OK, but you could simplify by removing the `if (dim)` test. You might want to document that you special case the last pixel to avoid computing an invalid pointer in `dst += dim`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, the `if (dim)` is superfluous. I needed it in some earlier experiment, but no longer.